# jQuery Find height of the largest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have six divs that all need to be the height as the one with the largest height.

For example if one div has 5 lines of text in it, and the others all have 2, then they all need to stretch to match the height of the one with 5 lines.

How can I do this by the elements' classes?

Comment: post your html css and javascript please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var mh=0; 
$(".some-class-name").each(function () {
    if (mh < $(this).height()) {
      mh=$(this).height()
    }
})
$(".some-class-name").height(mh);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       var el = $('.one'),
           elHeight = [];

       el.each(function(){       
           elHeight.push($(this).height());                                           
       });

       el.height(Math.max.apply(Math, elHeight));

    });
```

http://jsbin.com/qovacanari/1/edit?html,js,console,output